# How to add search icon with text as hint in Text Field ?

Tags: java, android, textfield

I want to add a search icon with text as hint in text field as photo below

> [image]

xml file

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="search" />
</EditText>
```

Comment: You have to accept the answer if it helped u @user3350437

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="search"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/youricon" />
```

in the `onFocusChange` of the `EditText`.

```
final EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean gotfocus) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gotfocus)
            {
                et.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
            }
            else if(!gotfocus)
            {
                if(et.getText().length()==0)
                    et.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.youricon, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

In your Activity file just add the following lines of code.

```
EditText filter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
filter.setHint("\uD83D\uDD0D Search");
```

Then remove the hint tag from the xml file.

Comment: This is a smart workaround, just bear in mind that refers to unicode character https://www.charbase.com/1f50d-unicode-left-pointing-magnifying-glass so do not expect any material search icon popping on the screen.

Answer (score 4):

You can  add a drawable to your EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="search"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_search" />
</EditText>
```

Comment: I want when click on textfield , the  hint text disappear with icon  ,not to put icon at the left

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_icon"
```

-

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_icon"
        android:hint="search" />
</EditText>
```

Comment: I want when click on textfield , the  hint text disappear with icon ,not
 to put icon at the left

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<EditText
    ...     
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If You dont want click on that Image, Then you can use drawableRight property for EditText..

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"
```

If you want click then use below code.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter search key" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/search"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

Comment: I want when click on textfield , the hint text disappear with icon ,not to put icon at the left

Comment: use this code <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_icon"
        android:hint="search" />
</EditText>

Answer (score 0):

Use this property of Editext

```
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_image_name"
```

Comment: I want when click on textfield , the hint text disappear with icon ,not to put icon at the left

Comment: Ok ! then you have to take another image and make edittext clickable in java by setting onclicklistner. When user click on edittext you have to change that image as background of that Edittext.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it dynamically. As soon as the person clicks the textfield, in the java file you can set drawableable left to none..

Answer (score 0):

//that is the `SearchView`

```
 <SearchView
       android:id="@+id/search"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:hint="search"
>

</SearchView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#searchHintIcon

From API Level 22 Only

Answer (score 0):

to work you add:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the answer is too late but it is for anyone have the same issue

> You can bind the image icon in the hint text using **ImageSpan**

```
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append(" ");
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.search_grey_icon),
            builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
    builder.append(" Search in okani");
    searchView.setQueryHint(builder);
```

Comment: not working i got this error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vadhod.dictcopy/com.example.myApp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (2130837606 ... 0) has end before start